# How to only took data that the status never change from beginning (SQL)

Tags: sql, mysql, select, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

i have a data like this in my SQL snowflake [image: samlpple data]

my expected value is i want only took the user_id that the status always 'low' never change from start to the end month[image]

I really stuck, how to only took user_id that status never change from beginning? I appreciate all answer. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `not exists` operator:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   mytable x
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                   FROM   mytable y
                   WHERE  x.user_id = y.user_id AND y.status != 'low')
```